# Python Pelican: How can I separate content by category?

Tags: python, pelican

I want to have a few elements on the menu:

- blog
- about
- projects
- texts
- experiments

I have 3 first items in the menu - blog is a folder with articles, about and projects are pages.
However, when I create another folder "texts" and add `.md` files to it, articles still appears under "blog" with 'texts' as a category.

I can manually create two Menue items and bound them to `text` and `blogpost` searches, but is there any more elegand way to separate content?

Comment: Does the [subcategory-plugin](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-plugins/tree/master/subcategory) help you with this? Do I understand you correctly?: `about` and `projects` are irrelevant to this question; all your articles are right now grouped under `blog` in their respective categories; you want `texts` and `experiments` to be containers like `blog`, which are able to contain their own categories and articles; articles are not shared between `blog`, `texts` and `experiments`.

Comment: Another possible solution: [Page Hierarchy](https://github.com/akhayyat/pelican-page-hierarchy)