# How to achieve the same behaviour than archives or pages in content folder with Pelican?

Tags: python, pelican

I would like that in the same way Pelican generates content using pages or articles folder and these is structured as page as file under `/pages/` path I would like how to do the same if I want for example have the same behavior with for example other folder called `products` in order to Pelican generate `/products/<file>.hml`.

```
content
   products
       product1.md
       product2.md
   articles
       article1.md
       article2.md
   pages
       about.md
       index.md
```

It should be easy (I think) to say Pelican that I want to process another folder inside content as it does, but I don't find the way.

Any idea? Maybe some Pelican plugin?

I've seen this answer: [Python Pelican: How can I separate content by category?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38880158/python-pelican-how-can-i-separate-content-by-category) but is not exactly that Ï want because he is talking about subfolders inside pages folder.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After messing with the available options, it seems that the path of least resistance in your scenario would be to set `PATH_METADATA` in your configuration file. Here is what you can have concretely:

```
# In pelicanconf.py
PATH_METADATA= '(?P<path_no_ext>.*)\..*'
ARTICLE_URL = '{path_no_ext}.html'
ARTICLE_SAVE_AS = '{path_no_ext}.html'
```

This will recreate the structure of `content` inside your `output` directory like so:

```
. (output folder)
├── about.html
├── archives.html
├── index.html
├── etc.
├── products
│   └── article-filename.html
│   └── article2-filename.html
├── articles
│   ├── article3-filename.html
│   └── article4-filename.html
├── pages
│   ├── article5-filename.html
│   └── article6-filename.html
```